# Terraform ignoring backend state store in S3 when running via CI/CD pipeline

Tags: gitlab, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have the following stage in my pipeline:

```yaml
run_plan:
  stage: plan
  before_script:
    - cd $CI_PROJECT_DIR/nonprod
    - terraform init
  script:
    - terraform plan
  when: always
```

The configuration for the backend looks like so in my `nonprod` module

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "my-cool-bucket"
    key    = "my-cool-key"
    region = "us-east-2"
  }
}
```

Now, when I run this locally, it's all good. `No changes` to apply. When the CI/CD pipeline runs this, it says that it's going to create a bunch of new resources. This shouldn't be the case given that I've specified a state location in S3 that replicates what local should be seeing, unless I'm wrong.

### Edit:

I've confirmed that it looks like Terraform auto created a parent key on top of my-cool-key despite not explicitly specifying it. The parent key is the name of the module, in my case `nonprod`. Therefore, when it went to pull, it was looking for `my-cool-key` and did not find it since it was under `nonprod/my-cool-key`. Updating the parent to be in the path fixed it.

Comment: Not sure, but if your edit is the solution, you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

I've confirmed that it looks like Terraform auto created a parent key on top of my-cool-key despite not explicitly specifying it. The parent key is the name of the module, in my case nonprod. Therefore, when it went to pull, it was looking for my-cool-key and did not find it since it was under nonprod/my-cool-key. Updating the parent to be in the path fixed it.